# Issues with Lxqt on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wireless, gnome, bluetooth, lxqt

Because of performance issues, I decided to switch from Gnome to Lxqt, following the guide at [linux config](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-lxqt-desktop-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) on my Ubuntu 20.04 installation, right of the bat, it flies, performance has greatly improved. However, I am experiencing challenges

I am unable to see whatever is displayed at the top bar: program name or date/time (first image below) and  in most windows i can barely make out any details (second image below). I down loaded an applied the theme 'Unitx', however only the panel is affected, the issue with visibility is not solved.
I also have the Kvantum theme [Sweet-Ambar-Blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVSGs.png) installed, however, it seems to only affect the file manager when directly accessed, when opened from other programs i.e while trying to upload the images below, the problem is back(see 2nd image).

[Here's my Widget Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oncvu.png) if its of any help.

[image]

[image]

I'm not usually adventurous with my main install and only made this switch for improved performance. I would appreciate help in anyone of the issues.

Thank you

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: Please be specific as to what apps you are having issues with; you appear to be wanting a darker theme (have you installed kvantum?) as you'll have more luck with that running, but you are aware GTK apps may follow GTK theming; where as LXQt desktop & apps will follow Qt theming; ie. ensure both themes match (*and why which apps give you issues is important*). Your top screen appears to be `pcmanfm-qt` but it's best if I'm not guessing, what text above windows?  do you mean window border? *as that's not handled by LXQt with Lubuntu using `openbox` for that so that's an openbox config...

Comment: Ensure your chosen GTK, Qt & WM themes all match  (*You didn't say how you added LXQt, as LXQt is WM agnostic, Lubuntu has chosen to use `openbox` but you can use whatever you wish, but it's the WM that draws & colors borders around windows - assuming that's what you're talking about in your 'top' picture*).   ps:  *I've ignored any reference to wifi as this isn't a forum but a Q&A site, where its one question per post; I've commented on the first thing you asked only*

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I've edited the question and added more information for clarity